# Where does Thunderbird store the expand/collapse icons for threaded messages?

Tags: email, thunderbird, icons, gnome3

I recently resolved [this issue](https://superuser.com/questions/917377/how-do-i-fix-oh-no-something-has-gone-wrong-gdm3-fails-to-start) but that left me with missing icons in threaded view in `thunderbird`.

My broken machine has a threaded view that looks like this:

[image: Missing Icon Image]

But it should look like this:

[image: Threads with correct icons]

So the only thing that is missing is the little triangle icon that let's you know that the thread is collapsed. I should note that the threads still expand correctly if you click where the button should be, you just have to know where it is.

So far I've tried turning threads off and then back on to see if something gets reloaded. I've reinstalled `thunderbird` and all it's dependencies. I've reinstalled a few `gnome-theme` packages that seemed relevant but they are still missing.

When I start `thunderbird` I see 30 or so lines that say:

```
(thunderbird:2529): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_lookup_icon_for_scale: assertion 'scale >= 1' failed
```

I also see this error when I mouse over the messages.

Comment: Years later and I land here with exactly the same issue and I see no solution posted :-(. The trhead expand icon has just disappeared. It works, it's just not there (I just have to click on the space where it would be). The thread collapse icon then appears!